# How can I get a uniform width on WPF ribbon elements?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, ribbon

I am creating a WPF application with a Ribbon, and the elements are all oddly sized. I want both of the text boxes to be the same width, although I also want the text to start at the same spot on the left side.

Ideally, this would addspace between the `Tags Loaded` label for the `RibbonTextBox` and the box itself. How can I do this so I get a uniform layout. All text should begin at the black line, and both `Text Boxes` should begin at the red line. At the very least I would like to extend the ending of the first `Text Box` to end where the second one does.

[image: Odd sizing for combo box]

Comment: Perhaps wrapping a grid around the label and textboxes with a shared size group. I think that is allowed in the ribbon controls.

Comment: Maybe you can align text boxes to the right?

Comment: The Label is a property of the RibbonControl. I didn't add it separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can redefine the template for `RibbonTextBox` to something like this:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type rb:RibbonTextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type rb:RibbonTextBox}">
                    <Grid   Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type rb:RibbonGroup}}}">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock   Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Label}" />
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1"   Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Text}"   />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```